# How do I break up a JSON object to insert into a MySQL table?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json

#### Summary

I have some JSON coming back me from this:

```
// Now Get Only New Listings
 finalArray = _.difference(existingResults, items);
```

and I need to insert those values into this:

[image: Columns]

Some of the data coming in is not available to fill in all columns. In that case, I would like to leave them blank.

Here is what the data looks like coming in (one of many presumably)...

```
{
    price: '$6,000',
    title: '1999 Jeep Wrangler SE Sport Utility 2D',
    location: 'Auburndale, Florida',
    miles: '12K miles',
    imgUrl: 'http://www.example.com/pic.jpg',
    itemURL: '/products/item/36427/'
  }
```

So I need to figure out how to go through every JSON object, and insert into the correct columns.

```
var insertQuery = 'Your code here! :)  ';
```

I suppose that query needs to be in a loop somewhere? Or one big insert statement?

Any advice or code would be really appreciated. Thanks.

---

### Note

Using: NodeJS and JawsDB MySQL ( in case that info is important )

Answer (score 0):

The following approach will ***only work if your payload doesn't have any nested objects***.Used ES6 Maps to do the work. I have used `connection.escape()` to remove any injectable scripts within the JSON to prevent SQL injection attacks. I hope that you have already install [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) connector for node.js.

```
const mysql      = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

const payload = {
    price: '$6,000',
    title: '1999 Jeep Wrangler SE Sport Utility 2D',
    location: 'Auburndale, Florida',
    miles: '12K miles',
    imgUrl: 'http://www.example.com/pic.jpg',
    itemURL: '/products/item/36427/'
}

const map = new Map(Object.entries(payload));
const keys = map.keys();
const values =  map.values();

const insertQuery = `
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (${connection.escape(keys.next().value)},
                        ${connection.escape(keys.next().value)},
                        ${connection.escape(keys.next().value)},
                        ${connection.escape(keys.next().value)},
                        ${connection.escape(keys.next().value)},
                        ${connection.escape(keys.next().value)})
            VALUES     (${connection.escape(values.next().value)},
                        ${connection.escape(values.next().value)},
                        ${connection.escape(values.next().value)},
                        ${connection.escape(values.next().value)},
                        ${connection.escape(values.next().value)},
                        ${connection.escape(values.next().value)});
`
connection.query(insertQuery, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // ...
});
console.log(insertQuery);
```

Comment: Building query this way allows for SQL injection attack. Why not build query properly with dedicated connector?

Comment: 100% agree with you Anastazy... I don't no why @John S. wanted such a way to create insert query..I hope he might know what he is doing...

Comment: I suggest you edit the answer and at least add some comment that doing it this way is vulnerable. In current form you are teaching how to get hacked.

Comment: Maybe I am going about this wrong. Here is what I am doing... I am scraping a page, and forming a JSON object that holds all the data. I am using Heroku as a server, so I can't write back to a JSON file ( the Dynos apparently sleep or something causing changes not to persist). Anyways, I created a mySQL db to hold my data. So I thought I would get back this JSON, and insert it into the DB. I certainly don't want to open myself up to SQL injection attacks. I simply want to take my JSON object and insert it into the proper columns in my DB. Is my post even on the right track?

Comment: @JohnS. Use proper escaping functions, everytime you have to deal with "untrusted" input – meaning you can't guarantee that it will be correct, and it comes outside of your code and you don't control it. Look here for more examples how it is done using the mysql driver https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values And never use simple string concatenation with untrusted input.